# Cannot find symbol 'getSystemService' in AudioManager

Tags: java, android, android-audiomanager

I am using the following code to create an instance of `AudioManager` :

```
AudioManager mgr = (AudioManager)getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
mgr.setStreamMute(AudioManager.STREAM_SYSTEM, true);
```

while compiling i get an error saying:

```
Cannot find symbol  : method getSystemService(java.lang.String)
AudioManager mgr = (AudioManager)getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
```

I also tried using :

```
AudioManager mgr = (AudioManager)Context.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
```

and I got the error:

```
non-static method getSystemService(java.lang.String) cannot be referenced from a static context
```

Which is the correct way of using the class and how can I avoid the above errors!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12555828/getting-a-cannot-find-symbol-method-getsystemservice-from-ant, you need use context of activity class instead of Context if you are not in activity class

Comment: You need a `Context` instance to use this method. Where is this code located?

Comment: @shayanpourvatan : i have gone through this post but it didnt help!

Comment: Have you tried cleaning your project? What's the context of the call of the method? As far as I can tell, you're calling the `getSystemService` method from a static context.

Comment: @matiash i am using this code in my camera app.

Comment: see my edit comment @Sid and if you are not in activity class use context of activity

Comment: so should i create and instance of Context class first and then use it?

Comment: you need pass context of activity to constructor of that class

Comment: Could you please post the block (Class, method) that surrounds the call to that method?

Comment: @Sid No, you need to receive a Context instance from somewhere. Please post the enclosing class.

Answer (score 3):

use following in your main activity class

```
Context context=getApplicationContext();
```

then pass context 
into your constructor of class in which you are creating AudiManager's object. Then use

```
AudioManager mgr = (AudioManager)context.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
mgr.setStreamMute(AudioManager.STREAM_SYSTEM, true);
```